# Recover the title from removed video from its YouTube ID

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to get the **title** for a YouTube video once it has been removed?

For example, I'm looking for a video (`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chGl0_nFyqg`) that was removed by the user. I'm pretty sure I can get an updated link for the video, *if I'd known what it was in the first place*.

[Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/) comes up blank.

Any other ways to get the meta info?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for but a google search of **chGl0_nFyqg** returns *Magic Pad* as the title.

When searching any of the Youtube video IDs (provided in the youtube link) on google it returns the videos titles so I would guess this one is right as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a service because I was also annoyed losing videos on my YouTube playlists which were set to private or have been deleted.

[www.recovermy.video](https://www.recovermy.video)

**What it does:**
It recovers the titles of deleted videos from the moment on you've used the service for the first time.

**What it can't do:**
Videos which were deleted before you've visited the service for the first time can't be recoverd. But you'll get a list of these videos with a link to google the videoIds as mentioned in Greg's answer.

Comment: This is a great solution, but it would be nice to be able to exclude playlists to be watched rather than monitoring every single one of my playlists for deleted videos. Also for reasons that I'm sure are understandable, I'm wary about giving my YouTube playlist data to an unknown developer. What assurance do you have on how you're using the data?

Comment: Hi Hashim, regarding the exclusion of playlists, I'm not sure if this is a common feature request. Feel free to propose it here: https://github.com/ninsky/recovermyvideotracker/issues

By using this service you grant read only permissions to your YouTube account. This type of permission is displayed to you at the Google OAuth dialog during registration. The data is used as described in the privacy policy which you have to accept when you want to register.