# How do I export my YouTube playlists?

Tags: youtube, export, youtube-playlist

YouTube likes to periodically delete videos that are on my favorites list:

[image: warning about deleted videos]

But they refuse to tell me what they were so I can go find another copy.

I would like a way to export my YouTube playlists, so that I can periodically diff them, and manually find other copies of the deleted songs.

How can I export my playlists (or a playlist) from YouTube?

Comment: For some reason viewing the playlist on an Android phone will still yield the names of the videos that were deleted!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there's no built in way to do this on Youtube.

You could of course use the Youtube API to easily get all of your playlists in xml using the following:

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[YOUR_USER_NAME]/playlists?v=2

*Example:*
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/oisinorion/playlists?v=2

That xml file will have the unique IDs for each of your playlists, which you can then use to get the details for each playlist, including Video URLs and titles.
The following API call will again give you an xml file:

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/[UNIQUE_ID]?v=2

*Example:*
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/D5F03C2BE1AA3E7E?v=2

Working with those XML files manually would be a nightmare however.
It would be best to create a small web app (if you know a bit of web programming) to pull out and present the relevant info from those XML files.

You can read more about the API here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists

Comment: It seems that only the first 25 items are returned by default. You can add `max-results=x` to the URL, but x > 50 is rejected. Add `start-index=...` for paging the results.

Comment: This answer appears outdated. Youtube API is now 3.0.

Comment: Just like the playlist itself, the API managed to bitrot in less than a decade. We live in a world where everything is just thought as temporary and no-one takes care of making things not disappear. Nothing will be known of our society in a thousand year because all traces will be gone.

Answer (score 24):

How about we make this more easy..

Go to: http://www.williamsportwebdeveloper.com/FavBackUp.aspx

Put in the playlist-url you want to create in excel-format, that's all :)

Here's a preview how it looks like. Have exported my short-film playlist which is located ***sorry not enough credits to post 2 links***
[image]

The creator:
*'All my web application does is use the YouTube developer’s API to get the feed data. You could do the same yourself but it would be in a complicated XML format and not very readable. I think most people would rather have it in an Excel spreadsheet. If you do not have Microsoft Office then you can download Open Office for free.'*

Comment: That works for all playlists except favourites and liked.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, I've been looking for *any* way to do this for 2 days, and there's so much outdated crap online related to this.  This site worked perfectly.  (just a little slow but still <2 days!) @tobylane `Liked` was the only list I was interested in and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @tobylane it works for favorites. I didn't test it for liked.

Comment: Nice, but your .xls is actually HTML. No need to open with Excel. Any web browser will display the file fine.

Comment: Does this work for Youtube Music playlists? I see that it doesn't

Answer (score 13):

This is not the most elegant way to accomplish what you ask, but here's a manual method that I just used to do it.  Because I'm using Powershell for part of this, I'm assuming you're on a Windows machine.

Steps:

1. Go to Google Takeout
2. On the Download Your Data page, deselect everything except for Youtube
3. Expand Youtube and select "Select specific data" under "YouTube data", then click the "YouTube data" button and select only "Playlists", then change the "Subscriptions" dropdown to "JSON", then click Next
4. Download your Takeout data when it's ready and unzip it to wherever
5. Open a Powershell session and execute the below statements

Assuming your playlist is Favorites, you'll get a Favorites.json.  Let's say I want just the title of each video in the playlist and a link to it, in a text file called YoutubeFavorites.txt:

```
$json = ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content .\Favorites.json -Raw)
foreach ($vid in $json) { "$($vid.snippet.Title) - Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$($vid.contentDetails.videoId)" | Out-File -FilePath .\YoutubeFavorites.txt -Append }
```

Voila, enjoy.

Comment: Seems like private playlists aren't exported (I only got 'liked' 'watch later' and something else that wasn't the playlist I was looking for)

Comment: That seems pretty weird, also disappointing.  Perhaps the API options in other answers are the only real solution(s).

Comment: My private YT Music playlists were perfectly exported via Takeout

Comment: Takeout doesn't have an option to download "Playlists" anymore. Is it under a different option now?

Answer (score 13):

In light of deprecation of v2, the current answer is no longer works. v3 is the new version.

The documentation link - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

This limits to only 50 results. 
Fill in the following

- API KEY with yyyy [(Link to get Credentials)](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
- pageToken NNNNN - from 2nd page on
- playListID - PLXxxx

Example link - 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=50&pageToken=NNNNN&playlistId=PLXxxx=key=yyyy

Comment: THANK YOU! 
Dozens of playlists from when the kids were younger, and I need to get them all organized and content sorted. This has been a total PITA. Hoping this (and other tidbits) pushes me in the right direction.

Comment: Does this works for Yotube Music playlists?

Comment: when this question was asked, music may not have existed. check the api

Comment: Yes it does, just tried it. However what it returns is not the names but just a [list of IDs](https://imgur.com/a/N9gvcDw). Which method should I run to get the human names for these IDs?

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays there are many solutions that do even more than what you requested:

- http://www.playlist-converter.net/ - Convert your playlist from multiple music services and file formats
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/youtubeexport/ - This program is used to export youtube playlists to text or .html files
- https://soundiiz.com/ - Upload playlists from files, web URLs or plain text, transfer your favorites between all streaming platforms, download to all popular files formats

**But the most efficient & elegant solution** would be in my opinion to just use [**youtube-dl**](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) because with one single command like (which you can easily build yourself by looking at the docs) you can download ALL your playlists items titles (well not only the titles, if you cared...), by entering as a parameter the YouTube URL to the page showing all your playlists (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/user/your_user_name/playlists). 
On top of that it also has an option to make authenticated requests to YouTube (with your credentials)  so it can also download your **private playlists**.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a service called [www.recovermy.video](https://www.recovermy.video) to fix this problem. See my [answer on another question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115511/180938).

Comment: Nov 2021 update: RecoverMyVideo will be dead by the end of this month. Thank you for your service, I've used it since I first came across this answer many years ago and it's a shame you're no longer to able to keep it going.

Comment: @HashimAziz, RecoverMy.Video will not shut down. See here:  https://www.recovermy.video/shutdown-postponed

Comment: Yes, I read the email a few hours after i posted my comment. I can't tell you how glad I am that you're looking into monetising, and I hope it works out for you and means the service can stick around indefinitely.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a new site we Developed https://www.tunemymusic.com/

You can choose export from Youtube a specific playlist, all your playlists and also all your liked videos.
Then you can export it for free text file.

In addition to text file, we are now working on adding options to export to csv and m3u files

Comment: I put a youtube playlist url into it and nothing happened.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/).

1. Deselect all
2. Scroll all the way to the bottom for YouTube and YouTube Music and select it [image: YouTube and YouTube Music in Google Takeout]
3. Click on All YouTube data included to get sub-selections and click Deselect all[image]
4. Select playlists and OK.
   [image]

Sorry, screenshot doesn't include OK. It's at the bottom of the modal where you select playlists.

5. Click Next step
6. Click Create export and wait a few seconds
7. Download

Comment: Just be aware that as of Nov 4 2020, this does not export ALL of my playlists. Only some random subset of them.

Comment: Edit Jan 2021: The above was actually fixed, and the previous limit of 50 playlists is gone. However, the CSV files now exported only have YouTube video code, not name of song. Sheesh.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) in your browser in order to catch the description of each video in the list and then print them all in a textarea.

For example this script will create a list with the url's and the names of the videos. Simply create a bookmark and add the following script in the address (URL) of the bookmark:

```
javascript:var Description = "Export YouTube playlists. This script is in the Public Domain - created at: 2016-11-21";
function printline(myLine) {
  document.write(myLine+"\n");
};
function showlinks() {
  var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth()+1;
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  document.write("<html><head><title>YouTube list: " + Title + "</title></head><body>");
  printline("<textarea name='Links' rows='55' cols='200'>");
  printline(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
  printline(Title +"\n"+url);
  printline("");
  for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) printline(lines[i]);
  printline("</textarea>");
  document.write("</body></html>");
};
var url = document.URL;
var body = document.body.innerHTML;
var lines = [];
if (url.match(/youtube.com/)) {
  var x = body.match(/data-list-title=.*/)[0];
  var x = x.replace(/.*data-list-title="/, '');
  var Title = x.replace(/".*/, '');
  var body = body.replace(/data-video-id="/g, 'data-video-id="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
  if (body.match(/li class=.yt-uix-scroller-scroll-unit/)) {
    var matches = body.match(/li class=.yt-uix-scroller-scroll-unit.*/g);
    for(i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
      var x = matches[i];
      var ID = x.replace(/.*data-video-id=./, "");
      var ID = ID.replace(/".*/, "");
      var VName = x.replace(/.*data-video-title=./, "");
      var VName = VName.replace(/".*/, "");
      var x = VName;
      var x = ID + "\t" + VName;
      lines.push(x);
    };
  };
};
showlinks();
```

In case you don't want the url's of the videos, then simply delete the line "var x = ID + "\t" + VName;" (line 36)

This script should work for a while, until YouTube will change the formatting of their HTML pages. When they will do that, you will have to adjust the script accordingly - most likely, you will have to search for something else instead of "data-video-title="

Answer (score -1):

What I did was go to my playlist and right clicked on the name of my playlist then selected "email with Windows Live". It sends a link to your email and when you click the link you have your entire playlist.

Comment: then YouTube removes a video from your playlist and then you go visit the emailed link again and you're taken to that playlist, where the video is now missing, you know? ;)

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you just open the playlist and copy/paste it to Excel, Word, or whatever?
It's not exactly elegant, but the information is there as a backup.