# How to see all YouTube likes if you liked over 5,000 videos?

Tags: youtube

Your [Liked videos playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL) has a limit of 5,000 videos. Is there any way to see all videos you liked, not just the last 5,000?

Actual number of liked videos is shown in stats on [Library](https://www.youtube.com/feed/library) page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google recently added a way to see all videos you liked and disliked, including time and date when you did it.

While logged in to your Google account, go to [Other Google activity](https://myactivity.google.com/more-activity) page, then search for "YouTube likes and dislikes" page.

If no likes/dislikes are shown on that page, you may have more than one YouTube account. Click your profile icon in upper right corner and pick another YouTube account.

Keep in mind that all items are shown on a single page, so browsing entire list when you have over 5,000 videos can be impractical, but this is currently the only way.

Comment: [Direct link](https://myactivity.google.com/page?utm_source=my-activity&page=youtube_likes). Note that if you have a *brand account* (aka "I didn't want to use my real name in comments or uploads") you have to switch to that to see your video activity.

Answer (score 1):

There was a tool posted [previously on Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82701/162876) which outputs a list of any Public playlist. NOTE: I have only tested this with a playlist of ~300, so I'm unsure if it will work for 5,000+.

1. Ensure that the playlist is **Public**.

   - This can be done from the YouTube > Settings > [Privacy](https://www.youtube.com/account_privacy) and clear the **Keep all my liked videos private** check box.
2. Navigate to http://www.williamsportwebdeveloper.com/FavBackUp.aspx.
3. In the **Enter YouTube playlist id:** field, enter the YouTube playlist ID.

   - For example, the *playlist ID* for "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5z_TDJiPV-VWaGkbTfGjmhphvWa6zbPp" would be **PL5z_TDJiPV-VWaGkbTfGjmhphvWa6zbPp**.
4. Click **Submit** and wait for the *xls* file to be generated.

   - NOTE: The playlist of ~300 took ~25 seconds to be generated. This may take longer for 5,000 videos.
5. Download and open the *xls* file.
6. Make your Liked Videos playlist **Private**, if applicable.

Comment: I already tried that website for saving playlist of 5000 videos, it crashed. I did manage to save my playlist with other program though. Still, my question was how to view 5000+ liked videos, not how to save playlists.

Comment: My apologies, I understood your question as wanting to _see_ the videos in your Liked Videos playlist. For future reference, what is the program that you were able to save your playlist with?

Comment: YouTube Export https://sourceforge.net/projects/youtubeexport/